# Unable to connect to Gitlab Container on Custom Port via SSH

Tags: git, powershell, ssh, gitlab

1. I have a VMWare Player, it is running a local VM that is hosting the Gitlab Server based on official container repo. I have changed the ports as follows:

   > Host → Container
   >   27→22
   >   85→80
2. I can access gitlab at the address `http://192.168.71.129:85/` from my browser.
3. I added the SSH key using GitHub's Git PowerShell into my Gitlab account that I can access locally.
4. I created a config file in my .ssh directory that has the contents as follows:

   ```
   #in gitlab.com server
   Host 192.168.71.129
   Port 27
   User git
   RSAAuthentication yes
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   ```
5. When I try to push to my Gitlab account using the following commands as shown in Gitlab:

   ```
   cd existing_folder
   git init
   git remote add origin git@gitlabhost:someuser/secondtest.git
   git add .
   git commit
   git push -u origin master
   ```

I get the following error from the last statement:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitlabhost: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

What setting am I missing? Any hints, suggestions?

Comment: Check that the SSH server on your Gitlab host is listening on port 27 (`netstat -ntlp`), and check that `git` is connecting to port 27 (`tcpdump port 27`). Also, you listed the remote host with its IP address in your SSH config, but used a hostname in the command. Check that the name actually resolves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message the hostname `gitlabhost` cannot be resolved:

> ssh: **Could not resolve hostname** gitlabhost: Name or service not known

You put the server's IP address in your SSH config:

```
Host 192.168.71.129
```

but used a hostname when setting the origin of your repository:

```
git remote add origin git@gitlabhost:someuser/secondtest.git
```

There are two ways to resolve the issue:

- Use the IP address in the origin:

  ```
  git remote add origin git@192.168.71.129:someuser/secondtest.git
  ```
- Ensure proper name resolution, e.g. by adding a line like this to `/etc/hosts`:

  ```
  192.168.71.129    gitlabhost
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ansgar Wiechers, below is my netstat output

```
$ netstat -l -t -n
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9344          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::8089                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::27                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::85                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Actually the problem was as you pointed out was the name resolution. I changed the command to just the IP address rather than host name and I was able to get it.

```
C:\Users\SomeUser\Documents\FirstPhPProj> git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/SomeUser/Documents/FirstPhPProj/.git/
C:\Users\SomeUser\Documents\FirstPhPProj [master +6 ~0 -0 !]> git remote add origin git@192.168.71.129:alamabbas/secondtest.git
C:\Users\SomeUser\Documents\FirstPhPProj [master +6 ~0 -0 !]> git add .
```