# Is it possible to install GitLab server on virtual machine with a invalid IP address?

Tags: gitlab, windows-10, vmware

I have installed GitLab server on a virtual machine (VMWare). GitLab IP address is 192.168.1.4 . I can see GitLab from browser. I generated ssh-key and added to GitLab server.

When I run `ssh -T git@192.168.1.4` I got this error:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.4 port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: Did you check VM firewall rules yet?

Comment: No. How I check this.

Comment: Is the VM running sshd?

Comment: @SiKing, sshd was not running

Comment: If the server (virtual or otherwise) is not running the ssh-deamon, how do you expect to connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

Not only you need to run SSHD in your GitLab server (type `netstat -l -t -n` to check that it listens on port 22, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36523962/6309)).

But you also need to check for:

- firewall rules
- [port mapping](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/mapping-a-port-on-the-host-to-a-specific-guest/m-p/2167486) (in your VMWare configuration)